# Default Alpha value of navigation bar in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

If you set `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` to `true` in your theme in Lollipop the navigation bar won't be fully translucent like in KitKat. Instead it's a dark semi-transparant background. Does anyone here know what the alpha value is of that background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made some test with navigation bar and found that alpha of navBar when `android:windowTranslucentNavigation = true` is 40% of black color.

So color in hex would be: `#66000000`

Here is steps how I calculated this value:

1. I made screenshot as presented below
2. Then I open it in Gimp image editor and take RGB values of each color
3. White is (255,255,255), white under navBar (153,153,153)
4. Grey is (150,150,150), grey under navBar (90,90,90)

Then I calculate as next:
255 is 100%
153 is  x
x = 153 * 100 / 255 = 60%

So I calculated invert value of alpha channel, the true value of alpha channel is 100 - 60 = 40%

ARGB value of 40% is `(102,0,0,0)` in hex it's `#66000000`

[image]