# Translucent status bar and toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

I'd like to integrate something like this:

[image]

And I've done it like this, but I can't seem to put the imageview below the toolbar. Without the toolbar, I can make it under the status bar, but combining these two are impossible.

[image]

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.project.android.PhotoActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/photo_tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#59000000"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />


</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity, I've done the following:

```
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

I've also declared an styles-v21.xml file:

```
<style name="Project.Photo" parent="Project.Light">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#59000000</item>
</style>
```

And set it as default style for PhotoActivity.
I've already tried putting the toolbar in a FrameLayout, but doing that my toolbar simply hides, like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Got that fixed, but toolbar is overlapping the status bar. Is there anyway to fix the padding? If I use         android:fitsSystemWindows="true", status bar isn't translucent anymore.**

Comment: Don't forget to check it on every version of android, since they changed the api every major version.

Comment: same problem refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738510/toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41707177/1543839

Answer (score 8):

I would remove the `Toolbar` from your layout and use an implementation of an `ActionBar` from the `AppCompat.Theme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then, I would create a new style for the semi-transparent `ActionBar` (in `values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And in `v21/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

I assume, that your `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity` so then in `onCreate()` you can call:

For enabling a back button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

For setting your translucent color:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourTranslucentColor)));
```

For removing your `ActionBar` title:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

What is more, I would change your root `LinearLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout` as it gives you more control over your layouts (it's a more powerful `FrameLayout`).

The color which I used is:

```
<color name="yourTranslucentColor">#29000000</color>
```

Of course you should remember to apply this theme to your `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

By doing all these steps you should get something like this:

[image]

Please let me know, if it works for you.

Answer (score 6):

As you said,

> "I've already tried putting the toolbar in a FrameLayout, but doing that my toolbar simply hides, like this:".

The problem with this is the order of adding childView in `FrameLayout`, you added Toolbar as first child and after that you added ImageView. this is why image hides the toolbar. Instead, the order of views inside `FameLayout` should be like this

```
<FrameLayout   
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          tools:context="com.project.android.PhotoActivity">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/photo_image"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:scaleType="fitStart" />

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/photo_tl"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="#59000000"
              tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Also for API level >=19 ,you can add this attribute in `style.xml` file to make statusBar transparent
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`
For making content behind statusBar use this link

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#behind

Answer (score 2):

Use code below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/YourTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Rest of your view-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For the image to fit the whole screen (fitXY), this doesn't work. It only works if I expand the AppBarLayout to match_parent. Is there another way to fit the image to the whole screen? Or is this wrong?

Comment: Plus I can slide the image up!

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` will automatically place the `ImageView` below the `Toolbar`.

Try using a `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: Probably better off with a `FrameLayout`

Comment: @CharlesDurham As I've stated, I've already tried putting the toolbar in a both FrameLayout and RelativeLayout, but doing that my toolbar simply hides.

Comment: @core_m Can you update showing how you used RelativeLayout and/or FrameLayout?

Comment: @core_m Your toolbar isn't hidden. It's drawn underneath the `ImageView`. You need to declare the toolbar second in the layout file.

Comment: @CharlesDurham Got that fixed, but toolbar is overlapping the status bar. Is there anyway to fix the padding? If I use         android:fitsSystemWindows="true", status bar isn't translucent anymore.

Comment: Did you try: <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: Define that in styles.xml

Comment: @BretDeasy I specified semi-translucent black color as my statusBarColor. The problem is that the toolbar overlaps status bar:
http://imgur.com/a/KWzRM
If i set fitsSystemWindows as true, my image isn't drawn underneath the status bar.

Comment: By the way, don’t use RelativeLayouts anymore, as of yesterday, Google recommended about them. ConstraintLayout can do the same and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Dont treat status bar as something separate from your app. Image is coming below the toolbar because you have used LinearLayout. Had you used RelativeLayout, your image would be starting at the same height as toolbar.

Now for making the statusbar transparent and for everything to start from under the statusbar use the following.

```
<style name="AppTheme.TranslucentStatusBar" >
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Use the above style for your activity and everything starts from under the statusbar. Now for the toolbar, you can increase the height of the toolbar by adding the height of the statusbar as padding to toolbar. This can be done as follows:

```
toolbarContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect frame = new Rect();
                getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
                toolbarContainer.setPadding(0, frame.top, 0, 0);
            }
        });
```

You can set a color to statusbar and use the same color with AlphaTransparency on Toolbar.

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
```

Now you control everything including the statusbar and the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

> Got that fixed, but toolbar is overlapping the status bar. Is there anyway to fix the padding? If I use android:fitsSystemWindows="true", status bar isn't translucent anymore.

I've recently written a post about WindowInsets, you may [check it out](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9#.fs3qg9crj). I think it would resolve your issue.

Long story short - what you have to do is to pass window insets only to `Toolbar` via `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetListener` API. But the parent of your `Toolbar` should pass the window insets. In your case that won't happen, because by default `LinearLayout` and family layouts won't do that, you have to subclass and override `onApplyWindowInsets` method.

I suggest you to read the article, where everything is described more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You have to wrap the toolbar in a LinearLayout.

What I did to make it work was similar to @Akhilesh Kumar's approach but I wrapped the toolbar in a LinearLayout which fixed the toolbar overlapping. I also put the fitsSystemWindows to true in that LinearLayout.

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.project.android.PhotoActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_card_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/photo_tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#59000000"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Also, thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466295/default-alpha-value-of-navigation-bar-in-lollipop the value of the translucent background is #66000000 instead of #59.

Answer (score -1):

just change the toolbar height to **wrap_content**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/photo_tl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#59000000"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```