# Android Toolbar set background color to semitransparent color

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to set the toolbar background color to a semi transparent color, on top of a Google Map.

I tried two things:

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#963f51b5"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Java:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(distanceText);

getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#963f51b5")));
```

None seem to work, which makes me think this is impossible?

Comment: Doing it in XML as you've shown should work.  I just did it today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work if you set the background of your `AppBarLayout` to transparent.

e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Add the rest of your views in here-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Needs to be at the bottom so it's shown over all the other views-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#963f51b5"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks! This should work, but I have problems with the themes.
@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay
@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay
With just adding it, the toolbar is not semi-transparent

Comment: Changing the theme to `@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay` like you had it should still work, see edited answer

Comment: The problem is still recurring: http://i.imgur.com/3THFN6E.png
It has to be transparent like in your image, but on my app it still shows a white layer on top, with either of the themes you showed

Comment: Does your mapView go right to the top of your screen? My guess is the white you're seeing is from the view under the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Yes it does. I dont want the mapview to move down, since the reason I wanted the toolbar to be transparent is to see the mapview beneath it

Comment: this works out fantastic with mMap.setPadding() for the Google Maps UI elements! thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fullhdpixel Beware, asymmetrical padding is extremely buggy.  Rotation, tilt, and orientation changes all ignore padding.  Google has ignored this issue for at least 4 years.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Just tried, seems to work fine with rotation.
http://i.imgur.com/fISBaXI.png http://i.imgur.com/R7eqzz5.png

Comment: @Fullhdpixel Rotate a few more times and watch your original center point move off the top of the map.

Comment: mmhh I dont see anything odd happen, rotated it at least 20 times.

Comment: @Fullhdpixel Are you setting the map position to that marker?

Comment: Original position: http://imgur.com/a/WWnhZ  After rotating to landscape and back twice: http://imgur.com/a/X9v7N

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, nothing odd happens

Comment: @Fullhdpixel If you're setting the map position after each orientation change, that's probably why you're not seeing the bugs: [#5881](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5881) [#6567](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6567)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, no there's no related code in my onConfigurationChanged. Haven't seen anything strange though. I will be alert if users start reporting related issues

Comment: @Fullhdpixel The bug occurs if you're *not* handling configuration changes yourself.