# How to have transparent Toolbar in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[image]

I always wonder on how to make Toolbar transparent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622957/translucent-status-bar-and-toolbar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761671/translucent-transparent-status-bar-coordinatorlayout-toolbar-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code can help

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

at your toolbar xml.