# In Android How do I change colour of status bar transparent as shown in bellow photograph

Tags: java, android

[image: This is a image of Android home screen.]

Can I change status bar colour like this in my app?

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313382/transparent-status-bar-in-android) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622957/translucent-status-bar-and-toolbar) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Comment: `I've seven years of android exp`. Tbh, if you had you wouldn't be asking this question. `Do not show your foolishness in public`. Cut the personal remarks. `How can you say I've not made any attempt?` You haven't shown any of your attempts. I'll not be replying to any of your comments in this thread. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change it's color, but I am not sure if changing it to transparent will have the effect you want

```
public static void setStatusBarColor(Activity activity, int color){
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this-:

```
private void changeStatusBarColor() {

        Window window = this.getWindow();
// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }
// finally change the color
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    }
```